# Modifying bibliography items to have alias names

Tags: bibtex

I defined the following macro:

```
\newcommand{\cmdAlias}[2]{\defcitealias{#1}{#2}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}}
```

Can I modify the `.bib` file such that the alias name is automatically retrieved from the bibliography (instead of running: `\cmdAlias{author:year}{AuthorFirstName AuthorLastName}`) For example, how can I modify the following reference to include an alias name for it, something like adding an `alias` key:

```
@article{dasi2007vorticity,
  alias = {Dasi {\it et. al}}
  title={Vorticity dynamics of a bileaflet mechanical heart valve in an axisymmetric aorta},
  author={Dasi, LP and Ge, L and Simon, HA and Sotiropoulos, F and Yoganathan, AP},
  journal={Physics of Fluids},
  volume={19},
  pages={067105},
  year={2007}
}
```

Comment: There is `@preamble{...}`, which can be used to define things in your `.bib` file; you could put your `\cmdAlias`-es there.

Comment: I don't want to put `\cmdAlias`. Actually I want to add a new entry for bibliography items and can be retrievable by for example `\cmdAlias{dasi2007vorticity}`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to give (say) your `dasi2007vorticity` entry any number of artibrary other bibkeys so you can cite that entry in several different ways?  If so, you may find [crosstex](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/egs/crosstex/) of interest.  But I don't understand how you are now suggesting `\cmdAlias` only takes one argument when it is defined in your question as requiring two arguments..?

Comment: You are right. The `\cmdAlias` takes two arguments. My question is how I can modify both this macro as well as adding an entry to bibliography items such that `\cmdAlias` automatically find this alias. For the example in the question, define a new macro such as `\cmdAlias2` that takes only one argument: `\cmdAlias2{dasi2007vorticity}` and outputs `Dasi et. al [1]`, where  1 is the citation number in the text.

Comment: `\cmdAlias2` sounds a lot like `\cite`; what is the difference?  I suspect better help will become available once you provide a complete, miminal document (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, especially one that lists how you are calling your bibliography and what style you are using.  I still think `\cmdAlias` would find any thing defined like `@preamble{ \defcitealias{#1}{#2}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}} }` in your `.bib` file, so it may be that we can do something similar for `\cmdAlias2`, but I don't see what advantage the new command has over `\cite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\citeAlias}[1]{\defcitealias{#1}{\citeauthor{#1}}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}}
\newcommand{\citeAliasTwo}[2]{\defcitealias{#1}{#2}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}}

\begin{document}


A reference with one author: \citeAlias{knuth:1974}. It is also possible to manually define the alias name: \citeAliasTwo{knuth:1974}{Donald E. Knuth}.

A reference with more than one author: \citeAlias{dasi2007vorticity}. 

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

The following is the content of the `mybib.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{knuth:1974,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {{C}omputer {P}rogramming as an {A}rt},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  year = {1974},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {667--673},
  number = {12},
  month = {December },
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  publisher = {ACM Press}
}

@article{dasi2007vorticity,
  title={Vorticity dynamics of a bileaflet mechanical heart valve in an axisymmetric aorta},
  author={Dasi, LP and Ge, L and Simon, HA and Sotiropoulos, F and Yoganathan, AP},
  journal={Physics of Fluids},
  volume={19},
  pages={067105},
  year={2007}
}
```

The result of the document is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `biblatex` this is pretty straightforward:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{knuth:1974,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {{C}omputer {P}rogramming as an {A}rt},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  year = {1974},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {667--673},
  number = {12},
  month = {December },
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  publisher = {ACM Press}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% from biblatex.def
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}} % <-- this line changed
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citefullauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{first-last}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newcommand\citealiasfull[2]{\citefullauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}
\newcommand\citealiasshort[2]{\citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

A macro with one parameter that provides the citation
and the author's name: \citealiasshort{knuth:1974}.
\citealiasfull{knuth:1974}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of what I am trying to have. I want to define a macro which has only one input and be able to produce both the alias name and the reference number hyper-linked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\citeAliasOne}[1]{\defcitealias{#1}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}}}
\newcommand{\citeAliasTwo}[2]{\defcitealias{#1}{#2}\citetalias{#1} \citep{#1}}

\begin{document}

Here, both the alias name and the reference number are hyper-linked:
\citeAliasTwo{knuth:1974}{Donald E. Knuth}.


Here, I am trying to only use one parameter to the macro and be able to mimic the
result of the macro {\tt citeAliasTwo}. Unfortunately, the result of {\tt citeAliasOne} 
is: \citeAliasOne{knuth:1974}, which is not what I want. In fact, I want to define a 
macro which gets one input and outputs both the alias name and the reference number 
hyper-linked. However, {\tt citeAliasOne} fails for this task.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Here is the content of mybib:

```
@ARTICLE{knuth:1974,
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {{C}omputer {P}rogramming as an {A}rt},
  journal = {Communications of the ACM},
  year = {1974},
  volume = {17},
  pages = {667--673},
  number = {12},
  month = {December },
  address = {New York, NY, USA},
  publisher = {ACM Press}
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]